# C# Ftp Upload in Windows 10 Universal app?

Tags: c#, ftp, windows-10, win-universal-app

I want to upload files from windows 10 app using ftp, I tried the following code.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Examples.System.Net
    {
        public class WebRequestGetExample
        {
            public static void Main ()
            {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
        byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        response.Close();
        }
    }
        }
    }
```

But visual studio couldn't find the name space `FtpWebRequest` or `WebRequestMethods`. The other method i tried using backgroundtransfer api's from [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj152727.aspx) but it says that  `WinRT information: 'uri': Uploading content is only supported for 'http' and 'https' schemes.` not ftp.

So is there any solution to this where i can show progress bar and speed?

Comment: Where are you trying to compile this app?  Which version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: @BlackFrog Sir i am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 community , and trying to run app from my mobile Lumia 530 win 10 latest preview build.

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313 Hi, did you succeed? I need to use FTP in UWP too...

Comment: @JanChalupa Sorry bro, i didn't get any chance to implement the code.

Answer (score 2):

The FtpWebRequest class is not part of the store profile for UWP apps, and FTP upload (as you determined) is not supported via the BackgroundTransfer API. This leave you with implementing your own FTP protocol over sockets. See [FTP Endeavor in WinRT](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/ftp-endeavor-in-winrt-i/) for an explanation and a link to a sample.

Comment: Thanks, will try and let you know, worked all the day and exhausted , going to sleep. my eyes are burning :) ;P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
https://github.com/kiewic/FtpClient

If you cannot open the project (e. g. with VS 2017), just take the two relevant classes from it.

Comment: I was interested in Windows Mobile app development. But since MS has abandoned the mobile. Not interested anymore. Thanks though.