# c# Windows 10 WebRequest and FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, windows-10, webrequest

Hope someone can help me with this.

I have been using this piece of code on Windows 8 without any trouble :

```
  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.100.42/FolderName/");
  request.Method = "NLST";
  request.Credentials = credential;
  using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
  {
      // Irrevelant operations (storing file names)
  }
```

On Windows 10 universal app, the GetResponseAsync method throws an exception:

> "Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed.\r\nParameter name:
>   requestUri"

The only relatively similar topic is this one :

[C# Ftp Upload in Windows 10 Universal app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380715/c-sharp-ftp-upload-in-windows-10-universal-app)

Also using FTP requests over WebRequest (FtpWebRequest is not available anymore), but his error was for upload specifically.

Comment: Looks like the solution is the same though, "This leave you with implementing your own FTP protocol over sockets."

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Kinda hope an other solution has been found.

Comment: Actually, this is an exact duplicate, as in both cases, it's `WebRequest.Create("ftp://...` that's failing